# C secp256k1: What is the purpose of the idiom '(void)data;'?

Tags: secp256k1

The following code is contained in the file `secp256k1.c`:

```
static void 
default_illegal_callback_fn( 
  const char* str, 
  void* data) 
{
  (void)data;
  fprintf(stderr, "[libsecp256k1] illegal argument: %s\n", str);
  abort();
}
```

Could someone explain the purpose of the line `(void)data;`? I am pretty sure there is one, but I can't figure out what it is :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Without `(void) data;`, gcc will complain about `data` being an unused variable. This is used throughout the codebase, especially for context objects, to deal with parameters which are required for API/consistency reasons but not actually needed.

Comment: Many compilers also have some variant of `__unused(data);`, which, if available, is preferred.

Answer (score 3):

Notice that without this cast, `data` would be unused in this function.  This is probably here for the purpose of preventing compiler warnings about unused variables, while keeping the argument in the function signature.

Comment: yes you are right, the cast `(void)` is necessary to avoid `gcc`'s warning. Thank you !